# Ciclo de vida Activity

Tags: android, activity, firestore

Tengo un problema con respecto al ciclo de vida del activity. Tengo una activity principal con bottomNavigationView y sus respectivos fragmentos. En la activity utilizo onStart() pára enviar a Firestore un boolean con su estado en linea.

Activity PanelPrincipal.java

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        UtilidadUsuarios.enLinea(fUser.getUid());
        super.onStart();
    }
```

clase UtilidadUsuarios

```
public static Task<Void> enLinea(String uid) {  
 return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(COLECCION_USUARIOS).document(uid).update("enlinea",true);
}
```

En PanelPrincipal tambien  utilizo onStop() y onDestoy() para enviar su ultima vez y su estado en linea falso.

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        UtilidadUsuarios.desconectado(fUser.getUid);
        super.onStart();
    }
    
  @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        UtilidadUsuarios.desconectado(fUser.getUid);
        super.onStart();
    }
```

UtilidadUsuarios

```
 public static Task<Void> desconectado(String uid) {
        return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(COLECCION_USUARIOS).document(uid)
                .update("enlinea", false,"ultimavez", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
    }
```

hasta ahí todo bien, pero me encontre con un problema :
cuando navego hacia otra actividad se me ejecuta onStop(), lo cual no quiero ya que sigue estando en la app.
Estoy utilizando onStop en el caso de que se encuentre la app en multiventana y el usuario cierre la app.
Quiero lograr que onStop se ejecute en multiventana y que no se ejecute en el cambio de activity(lo cual creo que es imposible) por lo que leí onStop se ejecutará si la activity no es visible.

¿Alguna alternativa para manejar este caso? Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola. Recuerda que es muchísimo más fácil explicarnos esto mostrándonos el código relacionado. Ese párrafo es impenetrable, toca imaginarse todo lo que nos estás intentando describir...

Comment: @Alfabravo listo :)

Comment: tu solución tiene muchos más problemas de los que encontraste.. La [documentación de firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-presence) explica como implementar esto correctamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con respecto a lo que comentas:

> En la activity utilizo onStart() pára enviar a Firestore un boolean
> con su estado en linea.

En realidad debes usar onResume() para asegurar que la Activity es visible y enviar/recibir información.

Con respecto a :

> Estoy utilizando onStop en el caso de que se encuentre la app en
> multiventana y el usuario cierre la app. Quiero lograr que onStop se
> ejecute en multiventana y que no se ejecute en el cambio de activity

Como lo comentas, esto es imposible ya que cada Activity tiene su propio ciclo de vida y onStop() es llamado cuando la Activity actual deja de ser visible.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que te recomiendo es usar una Activity que realice transacción de Fragments en lugar de tener varias Actividades, de esta forma controlarías tu app dependiendo del ciclo de vida de una sola Activity.

Answer (score -1):

Hola creo que deberías documentarte bien para que vas cuales son los estados que puede tener un activity, por lo que entiendo estás saltando el paso de onStop() y/o onPause(), aquí te dejo la documentación oficial y el diagrama de estados de los activities.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity
[image: Android lifecycle Activity]